# How to set invocation count during execution for the method using TestNG & Java

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, testng, invocation

I am having one test method, which I am manually executing for 200 times.

```
@Test(priority=2, invocationCount = 200)
public void inviteTalents() throws InterruptedException
{
  logger.log(Status.INFO, "Count " + logins[count]);
}
```

How can I set the invocation count variable? I have tried something like this, but doesn't work. Any help?

```
  @BeforeMethod
  public void setUp(Method method, ITestContext context) {

    if(method.getName().equals("test3"))
    {
        ITestNGMethod currentTestNGMethod = null;
        for (ITestNGMethod testNGMethod : context.getAllTestMethods())
        {
          if (testNGMethod.getInstance() == this)
          {
            currentTestNGMethod = testNGMethod;
            break;
          }
        }
        currentTestNGMethod.setInvocationCount(count);  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please supply output and given error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use an `IAnnotationTransformer` implementation to get this done.

Here's a sample that shows how to pass in the method name and the invocation count via JVM arguments and how the annotation transformer implementation changes the invocation count in runtime.

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn51160440;

import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassSample {
  @Test
  public void fooTest() {
    ITestResult r = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    String methodname = r.getMethod().getMethodName();
    System.err.println(
        "Running " + methodname + "() on Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "]");
  }
}
```

Here's how the annotation transformer looks like

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn51160440;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class AnnotationTransformerImpl implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  @Override
  public void transform(
      ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    //Pass the value via JVM argument -Dkvp=someMethod=400
    //Here "someMethod" is the name of the method and 400 is the invocation count value
    String kvp = System.getProperty("kvp", "fooTest=200");
    String keyValue[] = kvp.split("=");
    if (keyValue.length != 2) {
      return;
    }
    if (!testMethod.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(keyValue[0])) {
      return;
    }
    annotation.setInvocationCount(Integer.parseInt(keyValue[1]));
    annotation.setThreadPoolSize(25);
  }
}
```

Here's how the suite file looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="45160355_Suite" parallel="methods" verbose="2" >
    <listeners>
        <listener
          class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn51160440.AnnotationTransformerImpl"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="45160355_test" verbose="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn51160440.TestClassSample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps, but is there anyway that I can run all the threads in the same order.
For example, I am running 3 test cases in `TestClassSample` by giving priorities. And I want to execute those test cases according to given priority. From your example, threads are executing randomly and it's not executing in the same order.

**Output:**

`Running fooTest() on Thread [21]
Running fooTest() on Thread [18]
1. Hello

2. Test----Hello

Running fooTest() on Thread [19]
Running fooTest() on Thread [28]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BhavikGandhi - All you need to do is, disable parallelism by setting `parallel="false"` in the suite file that I have shared. After that you should see TestNG running the tests one after the other. Please accept my answer, if it has answered your question.